# Para qué se usa "%P" en Tcl?

Tags: tkinter, validación, tcl

Vi en este ejemplo de código para una validación de un entry, que usan "***%P***" en la comparación ¿qué hace exactamente y por qué se debe colocar?

```
entry .amount -validate key -validatecommand {
        expr {[string is int %P] || [string length %P]==0}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas -validatecommand estás especificando una validación para tu entry, que es la que esta dentro los brackets, y para traer el valor a validar dentro de tu condición la jalas con **%P**.

En el caso de tu validación, estas buscando checar que el valor del entry sea un string con formato entero a 32 bits o sea un string vacío.

Comment: Entiendo, funciona como un parametro o un argumento
Una última cosa, a que te refieres con String con formato entero? Me suena a algo como que el string se puede transformar en un entero, o sea solo numeros pero podrías aclararme eso por favor?

Answer (score 0):

el %P se usa para 2 situaciones:

la primera es en la validacion de un widget entry, devuelve en un evento el contenido de un entry, cuando se valida un entry, se puede validar evaluando si una condicion se cumple o no, si se cumple y la condicion devuelve true o 1 como paa en tcl, el entry permite seguir llenando el campo, por el contrario si la condicion devuelve false o 0 el entry no permite mas caracteres y se bloquea el entry tanto asi que no deja siquiera borrarlo con backspace. el comodin %P devuelve el contenido del entry.

la segunda es en el formato del tiempo, el parametro %P, hace que se muestre la condicion am o pm